# "An operation is not legal in the current state" error when trying to launch ASP.NET project in VS2013?

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, visual-studio-2003

I have an ASP.NET web site created with WebMatrix 3.  I do have the option in VS2013 checked to use the 64-bit version of IIS Express since I am running on 64-bit Windows 8.1.  When I try to launch the project I get the error "An operation is not legal in the current state".  Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: did you ever figure this out

Answer (score 3):

I got this same error "An operation is not legal in the current state" when running a project on Google Chrome, Stopping the project then closing all chrome instances fixed the problem.

I think it's related to visual studio not being able to attach to chrome instance for debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Closing *Chrome* and restarting IIS (e.g. in *IIS Manager*) should solve the issue. It helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue on VS (Visual Studio) 2017 this morning.
The steps that will resolve this are:

1. Stop project that runs in VS
2. Clean all IIS instances that VS temporarily created
3. Compile project and start that service again